# lz4 redirect output to /dev/null

Tags: bash, tar, lz4, dev-null

I have the following command in my bash script and want to redirect the output to /dev/null but it is not working. What is the right way to achieve this?

```bash
tar cvf - -C / $SOURCE_DIR | lz4 --best - $ARCHIVE > /dev/null
```

**Edit:**
Example output (I'm creating an archive of the `/home/philip/test` folder):

```bash
home/philip/test/  
home/philip/test/test.txt
```

**I want the above output to be redirected to /dev/null.**

--$SOURCE_DIR is the folder I'm archiving. Ex: `home/philip/test`
--$ARCHIVE is the destination path where the archive is saved. Ex: `/home/philip/temp.tar.lz4`

Comment: It's probably outputting to stderr. Try adding `2>&1` to the end of that line

Comment: What's the point of using `tar -C /`? it's superflous when `$SOURCE_DIR` is an absolute path, and gives unexpected results when the `$SOURCE_DIR` is a relative one.

Comment: @Fravadona I was getting `remove leading '/'`, so I'm using `-C /`. After this there is no unexpected results.

Comment: @EmanuelP I am checking the exit code of the command, and it is 0, so I don't see why output would be redirected to stderr. Nevertheless, I did try `2>&1` and this also didn't work.

Comment: @TrevorPhilip Some programs write generic status messages to stderr, because they use stdout for the output file. It's a bad practice, but I've seen it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both commands might also **errput** messages when a problem occurs, so I don't recommend muting their stderr completely; I would just rework the command line in a way that limits their stderr to warnings/errors only:

```bash
tar cf - "$SOURCE_DIR" | lz4 -9 - > "$ARCHIVE"
```

Comment: I did try this as well, but I can still see the file names in the output that will be archived. The output is not being redirected to /dev/null.

Comment: @TrevorPhilip I don't think that you tried the command... removing the `-v` option of `tar` disables the file listing (and the `remove leading '/'` message); not providing a file name to `lz4` makes it silent.

Comment: Thanks, I was stupid not to execute the command. I didn't notice that `-v` option was removed.